# Reference part of list item in loop

Tags: python

I am trying to turn a txt file into a new txt file with specific formatting so i can put it straight onto a website.

I have created a list called stats of the items to go under the Statistics heading but am now trying to write the loop to tell it to format the text in a specific way and I'm getting invalid syntax errors.

Here is what I have so far..

```
txt = open(html_file, 'a')
    txt.write('<h5><a href="http://www.learningplusuk.org/data/education-reform" target="_blank"><strong>Education Reform</strong></a></h5>'
            '\n'
            '<p>All the latest information on qualification reform can be found via our website, in the ‘Education Reform’ section.</p>'
            '\n'
            '<hr>'
            '\n'
            '<p>Statistics and Data</p>'
            '\n'
            '<hr>'
            '\n')
for i in stats:
    j,k = enumerate(stats.split("\t"))

txt.write('<h5><a href=/"'i.split("\t")[4]'" target="_blank"><strong>'i.split("\t")[1]'</strong></a></h5>'
            '\n'
            '<h5><strong>'i.split("\t")[2]'</strong></h5>'
            '<p>'i.split("\t")[3]'<br></p>'
            '<hr>'
            '\n')
txt.close()
```

but it says the i.split is invalid syntax. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to concatenate strings? Yes, this is a syntax error... `txt.write('<h5><a href=/"'i.split("\t")[4]'`

Comment: I hope the contents of `stats` are not coming from an untrusted source (say: a random visitor to your web page). :-]

Comment: you cannot concatenate strings like that. there are many ways to do it but try `+` between terms like: `'<h5><a href=/"' + i.split("\t")[4] + ...`. Enclosing a variable in quotes does not convert it to string. Also look at this (https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the + operator when concatenating strings: `'<h5><a href=/"' + i.split("\t")[4] + '" target=...'`

Comment: Got it in the end! Thank you guys! The data is from government data releases so reliable (hopefully!)